# Convert date field to mm/dd/yy format in visual foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a date value mm/dd/yyyy format in visual FoxPro. while fetching I want to convert it to mm/dd/yy.

Want to know how we can achive this.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear. A date field is always stored as a 'date' regardless of the display format. What you are saying is a display format. You can achieve it in multiple ways. ie:

```
set century off  && default
set date MDY
```

or:

```
set century off 
set date AMERICAN && default
```

If what you meant is just to use 2 digits for century actually it is the default, if changed in your config.fpw then simply use:

```
set century off
```

Note: Both "set century" and "set date" are scoped to current data session.